# Numerically solving system of partial differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am trying to solve a system of partial differential equation with boundary conditions. But I got an error message saying

> `NDSolve::icfail:` Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the
>   residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial
>   conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.`

As I understand it, this is due to the absence of a system of equations of derivative with time of function G[t,x] and L[t,x] and solve this system can only be effected by The Numerical Method of Lines.

```
 Remove["Global`*"]; 
pde = {
  (-Derivative[1][Y21][t] - Derivative[1][Y31][t]) == -X20[t] - 
    X30[t] + Y21[t] - G1[t] (1 - Y21[t] - Y31[t]) + Y31[t],
   Derivative[1][Y21][t] == 0.01` - Y21[t] - G1[t] Y21[t],
  Derivative[1][Y31][t] == 9.9` + X30[t] - G1[t] Y31[t],
  (-Derivative[1][X20][t] - Derivative[1][X30][t]) == 
   0.2` + X20[t] - L0[t] (1 - X20[t] - X30[t]) + X30[t] - Y21[t] - 
    Y31[t],
  Derivative[1][X20][t] == 0.79` - L0[t] X20[t] + Y21[t],
   Derivative[1][X30][t] == 0.1` - X30[t] - L0[t] X30[t]}
```

with boundary condition:

```
BC = {
  Y21[0] == 0, Y31[0] == 1,
  X20[0] == 0.8, X30[0] == 0,
    G1[0] == 10, L0[0] == 1
   };

desired = {Y21, Y31, X20, X30, G1, L0};
NDSolve[{pde, BC}, desired, {t, 0, 1000}];
```

I tried to discretize the system in space using the finite-volume method. (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html).

Maybe somebody knows the alternative method of solve that type of equations?

It is a system of differential equations describing the process of countercurrent extraction. On top of the extraction column enters the two liquid components. The gas phase enters to the bottom of column. Liquid components have different solubility in the gas phase, due to which they are separated - coming out on top of the column the gas phase enriched by one component and the liquid phase exiting from the bottom - the other. This is the differential material balances for each component in the gas and liquid phases. The boundary conditions are taken from the known composition of the feed liquid phase on top of the column (z = 10) and the known composition of the gas coming from the bottom (z = 0) is also assumed that the initial time t = 0 corresponds to the equilibrium of the two streams at full lack of mixing.
All constant parameters I removed for readability equations. 
Detailed description of the output of the system of equations described in the article: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3oewg2w3etszbu/article.pdf. The authors solved a similar system using the method of lines in the software package gproms. The system was discretised in space using the finite-volume method. I'm trying to solve this problem in the software package Math, using "MethodOfLines" technique, but unfortunately so far without success. I would be very grateful for any help in this matter.
I apologize for my English is not the native language for me.

Comment: I think your question will draw more attentions if you add some background information of the set of equations.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you, I added

Comment: and maybe a rack of GPU processors...

Comment: Maybe you can also talk about how you created this set of equations, I mean, you can tell us what's the law behind the equations.

Comment: " …is also assumed that the initial time t = 0 corresponds to the equilibrium of the two streams at full lack of mixing. "By saying this, do you mean that the system has already been in equilibrium state at beginning? And due to your description of the background, I guess this set of equation is based on [Fick's first law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion), right? If so, I think your equation is incorrect, you'd better check it first.

Comment: @xzczd I wrote the interphase mass fluxe equations for each component between the liquid and gas phases:
Yi[z, t], {t}] == Ji[z, t] - D[G[z, t]*Yi[z, t], {z}]
Xi[z, t], {t}] == -Ji[z, t] + D[L[z, t]*Xi[z, t], {z}]

And the material balance equation for each component:
Ji[z, t] == Ki*(Yieq - Yi[z, t])

where Yi - gas phase composition, Xi-liquid phase composition,
Ki- mass transfer constant
Yieq, Xieq - equilibrium compositions for liquid and gas phase
D and L - gas mass flowrate and liquid mass flowrate

Comment: @xzczd For the system to be solvable I removed 2 components using expressions are obtained from the mass fraction constraints:
1 == X1[z, t] + X2[z, t] + X3[z, t], 
1 == Y1[z, t] + Y2[z, t] + Y3[z, t],

Comment: So, the answer to my two questions above is? By the way, your first language is?

Comment: @xzczd My native language is Russian. 
So I don't know the name of rule, but it is not the fick law, we call it Newton-Shukerev law, its assumed that mass flow is proportional the difference between equilibrium concentrate of component and its real concentration at the time near the phase boundary.
I assure that this system of equation is correct because I take this model from the article, where authors successfully implement this model to their system, but they use different  math package to solve this system of equation. I just want to implement the mathematica package. 
Thanks.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, right, system has already been in equilibrium state at beginning.

Comment: @xzczd Link to article: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v3oewg2w3etszbu/article.pdf

Comment: OK, let me have a look… maybe you can add all these to your question so the question will rise to the top and more people will see these complement.

Comment: After reading the article, I think the 3rd equation should be `D[1 - Y2[t, x] - Y1[t, x], t] == -D[G[t, x] (1 - Y2[t, x] - Y1[t, x]), x] + xb3 - (1 - X2[t, x] - X1[t, x])` and the 6th should be `D[1 - X2[t, x] - X1[t, x], t] == D[L[t, x] (1 - X2[t, x] - X1[t, x]), x] +(1 - X2[t, x] - X1[t, x]) - xb3}` where `xb3` is the equilibrium concentration of CO2 in liquid, also, maybe we should also add `yb1` and `yb2` to the other equations, but I still cannot solve the equations with all these modifications…

Comment: @xzczd , also have an all-no more promotions(

Comment: I also noticed that the same warnings still exist when I take away those `X2`s and `Y2`s in `pde` and `bc` i.e. the liquid phase is reduced to a pure substance. So, just a suggestion, maybe you can simplify the `pde` and `bc` in your question a little more.

Comment: @xzczd symplifyed, thanks